# Can not set period/timeout option for ffmepg

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried to capture streaming via rtsp and limit the clip duration under `3 sec`

But the option doesn't work. The ffmpeg won't be terminated anymore.

Is there any workaround to fix the problem.

Because I have to run hundreds of similar commands in a batch with Python script.

```
ffmpeg -loglevel verbose   -i rtsp://172.19.1.42/live.sdp -acodec copy -vcodec copy  c0_s1_h264_640x480_30_vbr_500_99_40000000.mp4 -timeout 3 -y
```

> $ ffmpeg -h ffmpeg version 1.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg
>   developers   built on Nov 22 2013 11:59:59 with Apple LLVM version 5.0
>   (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)

The detailed log at  https://gist.github.com/poc7667/8234701

Answer (score 7):

From your console output:

> `Trailing options were found on the commandline.`

[Option placement](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Synopsis) matters:

```
ffmpeg [global options] [input options] -i input [output options] output
```

How is `ffmpeg` supposed to interpret your trailing options? Your command should look like:

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel verbose -timeout 3 -i rtsp://172.19.1.42/live.sdp -acodec copy -vcodec copy  c0_s1_h264_640x480_30_vbr_500_99_40000000.mp4
```

See the [FFmpeg RTSP Protocol Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtsp) for more information, but you should refer to your local copy of your docs since the online docs are synced with current code from Git master and your `ffmpeg` version is old.

Comment: I get `-timeout Option not found`

Comment: @chovy Please use a pastebin site to show your command and the complete output. Then provide the link in a comment.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use **stimeout** parameter:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -i rtsp://172.19.1.42/live.sdp -acodec copy -vcodec copy c0_s1_h264_640x480_30_vbr_500_99_40000000.mp4 -stimeout 3000 -y
```

Note that you should use microseconds with stimeout param

Comment: Looks like the placement at the end is ignored, `Trailing option(s) found in the command: may be ignored`. Earlier answer had older option but correct placement.